# Collection type re-mapping with Blaze Persistence

Tags: hibernate, blaze-persistence

I'm using the Entity View Module of Blaze Persistence for mapping the following Hibernate entities to DTOs.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "configuration")
public class ConfigurationEntity {

  @Id
  private UUID institution;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "configuration", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<DescriptionEntity> descriptions;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "description")
public class DescriptionEntity {
  @EmbeddedId
  private Identifier identifier;

  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId("identifier_institution")
  @JoinColumn(name = "identifier_institution")
  private InstitutionConfigurationEntity configuration;
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class Identifier implements Serializable {

  private UUID institution;
  private String language;
}
```

Using an entity view where all child entities are stored as a list works without problems. However, instead I want to create a Map<String, DescriptionView> where the key refers to DescriptionEntity.Identifier.language and values are views of DescriptionEntity.

According to documentation (https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/entity-view/manual/en_US/#collection-type-re-mapping) the `@MappingIndex` should be used for that. But even for the simplified case when using DescriptionEntity.name instead of the composite key, the library always throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute 'name' not found on type 'ConfigurationEntity'`.

```
@EntityView(ConfigurationEntity.class)
public interface InstitutionView {
  @IdMapping(value = "institution")
  UUID getIdentifier();

  List<DescriptionView> getDescriptions(); // this works

  @MappingIndex("name") // Attribute 'name' not found on type 'ConfigurationEntity'
  Map<String, DescriptionView> getDescriptions(); // this doesn't
}
```

I'm having a hard time understanding why blaze would think the `name` attribute would be in `ConfigurationEntity` instead of `DescriptionEntity`. This has led me to believe that the entity relations are not defined properly, but I have reviewed them over and over again and couldn't find anything (I'm using `hibernate-orm.implicit-naming-strategy=component-path` by the way, meaning that the composite key columns are named `identifier_institution` and `identifier_language`).

I would be glad for any recommendations on how to solve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in the type validation code related to the fact that your one-to-many mapping uses `mappedBy`. I think it tries to find the attribute for the mapping index in the type that the `mappedBy` path refers to, which is `ConfigurationEntity`, but the resulting query would still be correct.

I just ran a quick test and was able to reproduce your issue, and now also created a GitHub issue for this: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/issues/1695

You have two ways to workaround this until this bug is fixed:

- [Disable validation](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#EXPRESSION_VALIDATION_DISABLED) (not really recommended)
- Introduce a temporary field with the same name in `ConfigurationEntity` e.g. `@Formula("null") String name`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply - awesome library by the way!